# jquery validation for Date "MM/YYYY"

Tags: jquery, validation, date, format

I am using jQuery Validation Plugin ( http://jqueryvalidation.org ) for credit card validation. How can i make them to put exactly date in mm/yyyy format using this plugin?

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$('form[name="submit_cc"]').validate({
  rules: {
    holder_name: {
      required: true,

    },
      cardnumber: {
      required: true,
      creditcard: true
    }


  }
});
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Lalit for your answer it works.

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
      debug: true,
      success: "valid"
    });
    jQuery.validator.addMethod(
            "trioDate",
            function(value, element) {
                return value.match(/^\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/);
            },
            "Please enter a date in the format mm/yyyy"
        );

    $('form[name="cc_frm"]').validate({
      rules: {
      dob: {
                        required : true,
                        trioDate:true
                    },
        CardNumber: {
          required: true,
          creditcard: true
        },

         CardType: {

          required:  true
        }

      },


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom validation method using the addMethod function. Say you wanted to validate "mm/yyyy":
    "Date",
    function(value, element) {
        // put your own logic here, this is just a (crappy) example
        return value.match(/^\d\d?/\d\d\d\d$/);
    },
    "Please enter a date in the format mm/yyyy."
);                                                                                        and in your form  $('#myForm')
    .validate({
        rules : {
            myDate : {
                Date : true
            }
        }
    })
;

Answer (score 0):

May will important to validate if the month is a month and the year is a year. I did a little change in the regex pattern to help.

```
$.validator.addMethod('cardexpiry', function( value, element ) {
  return value.match("(0[123456789]|10|11|12)([/])([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])");
}, "Precisa ser no formato mm/aaaa" );
```

**UPDATE FOR 2020's**

```
$.validator.addMethod('cardexpiry', function( value, element ) {
  return value.match("(0[123456789]|10|11|12)([/])([2][0][2|3][0-9])");
}, "Parece que tem algo errado"   );
```